# SendMail not working in CentOs 6.4

Tags: centos, smtp, sendmail

I am trying to send e-mails from my CentOS 6.4 but it does not work. My knowledge about servers is quite limited, so I hope someone can help me. Here is what I did:

1. First  i tried to send an email using the "mail" command, but it was not in the OS so I installed it.

   ```
   # yum install mailx
   ```
2. After that, I tried sending an email using the "mail" command, but it did not send anything. I checked it on the internet and I realized I needed an e-mail server like sendmail, so I installed it.

   ```
   # yum install sendmail sendmail-cf sendmail-doc sendmail-devel
   ```
3. After that, I configured it following some tutorials. First, sendmail.mc file.

   ```
   # vi /etc/mail/sendmail.mc
   ```
4. Commented out the next line:

   ```
   BEFORE
   # DAEMON_OPTIONS('Port=smtp, Name=MTA') dnl

   AFTER
   # dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS('Port=smtp, Name=MTA') dnl
   ```
5. Check that the next lines are correct:

   ```
   # FEATURE(`virtusertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/virtusertable.db')dnl
   # ...
   # FEATURE(use_cw_file)dnl
   # ...
   # FEATURE(`access_db', `hash -T<TMPF> -o /etc/mail/access.db')dnl
   ```
6. Update sendmail.cf

   ```
   # m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
   ```
7. Open the port 25 adding the proper line in the iptables file

   ```
   # vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables

   # -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
   ```
8. restart iptables and sendmail

   ```
   # service iptables restart
   # service sendmail restart
   ```

So i thought that would be ok, but when i tried:

```
    # mail 'test@gmail.com'
    # Subject: test subject
    # test content
    #.
```

I checked the mail log:

```
    # vi /var/log/maillog
```

And that is what I found:

```
    Aug 14 17:36:24 dev-admin-test sendmail[20682]: r7D8RItS019578: 
    to=<test@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<root@dev-admin-test.localdomain> (0/0), 
    delay=1+00:09:06, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=2460500, relay=alt4.gmail-
    smtp-in.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with 
    alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

I do not understand why there is a connection time out. Am I missing something? Can anyone help me, please?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Kane! Looks like it cant connect to `Connection timed out with    alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.`, is that host reachable from your mail server (outgoing 25)?, you can try with netcat or something to see weather you can connect...

Comment: Hi Petter! I used "nc -C alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25" but there is no response. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: What sort of network are you on? Your ISP could be blocking port 25.

Comment: A tutorial told you to stop sendmail listening on port 25, but to open the firewall port for incoming port 25 connections? I think you found a bad tutorial there...

Answer (score 4):

## Outgoing SMTP connections blocked by a firewall

Are you sure your outgoing SMTP connections are not blocked by a firewall?
It is a common outgoing spam precaution.

Do you get SMTP greeting message when you telnet port 25 and 587 on smtp.gmail.com?
[You should get the greeting at least on port 587]

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
telnet smtp.gmail.com 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the answers. It seems the smtp server that is being used in my place was not configured in the config file. I got the correct info, write it in the config file and now it works fine.

Thank you!

Comment: Please consider adding the changes you made to your configuration files, or any other thing you may think is relevant to the solution for future reference.